# How to make x2go’s windows get focus on click?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, focus, x2go

#### The problem

I use x2go and both client and server side have i3 as wm. So, the problem is the conflict between each key bindings. When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> on the distant system’s window it affect the local system… so it’s very painful.

#### A kind of solution I search

So, with Virtualbox, the hosted system’s windows get the entire focus on click. All key-binding I press goes to it. When I want to left the hosted system’s window, I press a button (typically left <kbd>Control</kbd>). So how can I get the same behavior with x2go ?

Answer (score 0):

X2Go is using nx-libs. A feature like this is currently being implemented and will probably be included in the next release of nx-libs (3.6.0), see [this bugtracker issue](https://github.com/ArcticaProject/nx-libs/issues/384)